# No connection between Online Accounts and Pidgin?

Tags: 17.04, pidgin, online-accounts, messaging-menu, instant-messaging

Running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

I have added my Google account in the Online Accounts. It is enabled for chat.

Yet when I start Pidgin for chatting, it keeps asking me to add an account.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I tell Pidgin to look-up Online Accounts?

Also, there is no messaging menu where I can set my online status, etc.

Comment: I believe you'll have to manually set up your google account with Pidgin (which is pretty cumbersome). If I remember correctly for the chat option in Online Accounts to work one needs Empathy.

Comment: I think there's no Pidgin plugin for Online Accounts, unfortunately.

Comment: @pomsky That's funny because Empathy is not installed by default. Pidgin is! :)